# What's the replacement for FlutterMain

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The code I tried to start callback for my background service.

```
public class PushService extends JobIntentService implements MethodCallHandler {
    private static FlutterEngine backgroundFlutterEngine = null;

        private void startPushService(Context context) {
        synchronized (serviceStarted) {
            if (backgroundFlutterEngine == null) {
                final Long callbackHandle = PushStore.getInstance().getPreferenceLongValue(
                        PushPlugin.CALLBACK_DISPATCHER_ID, 0L);
                if (callbackHandle == 0L) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Fatal: no callback registered.");
                    return;
                }

                final FlutterCallbackInformation callbackInfo =
                        FlutterCallbackInformation.lookupCallbackInformation(callbackHandle);
                if (callbackInfo == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Fatal: failed to find callback info.");
                    return;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Starting PushService...");
                backgroundFlutterEngine = new FlutterEngine(context);
                DartCallback args = DartCallback(context.getAssets(), FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath(context), callbackInfo);
                backgroundFlutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartCallback(args);
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the FlutterMain is deprecated, how to do the new way to execute dart callback?

Comment: This is actually documented in [FlutterMain](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/view/FlutterMain.html): **Deprecated.** 
Replaced by [FlutterLoader](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/loader/FlutterLoader.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlutterMain has been replaced by [FlutterLoader](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/loader/FlutterLoader.html), from what I understand.

Edit:
On the [FlutterMain documentation page](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/view/FlutterMain.html), right underneath the first horizontal divider, it mentions this replacement.